# Using diode to protect controller input

Tags: diodes, circuit-protection

I'm looking to use [inductive proximity sensors](http://www.clrwtr.com/PDF/SUNX/SUNX-GL-8U-Proximity-Sensors.pdf) on a [Duet Wifi](https://www.duet3d.com/DuetWifi) (3D Printer Control Board), the board itself runs 3.3v but the sensors require 12-24.  I've asked this on the product forum and they pointed me to some [documentation](https://duet3d.dozuki.com/Wiki/Connecting_a_Z_probe#Section_NPN_output_normally_open_inductive_or_capacitive_sensor) that says to use a diode as follows:

> NPN output normally-open inductive or capacitive sensor
>
> Connect its output wire to the cathode of a diode, and the anode of the diode to
>   the E0 STP pin. Connect the sensor ground wire to a ground pin on the
>   Duet, and the sensor's + power wire to a suitable voltage (typically
>   to VIN because these sensors usually need between 6 and 30V power).
>
> The diode should preferably be a small-signal Schottky diode such as
>   BAT43 or BAT85, but a small signal silicon diode such as 1N4148 works
>   for some people.

How is the diode working in this scenario?  It appears to be placed backwards and if I use 24v, that isn't enough to reach the reverse breakdown voltage of any of the recommended diodes.

Comment: Draw what you think they have told you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The sensor uses a pull-down transistor which is on (pulling down) when the sensor is tripped and not doing anything otherwise. I believe they're suggesting the following:
[image]

This implies that the Duet Wifi's input pin has a built-in pull-up resistor. The pin's value is normally at 3.3v unless pulled down by the sensor. Thus the Duet's pin actually provides current out of its 3.3v supply through the built-in pull-up resistor into the sensor's pull-down transistor. The diode ensures that current can only come out of the Duet's pin, preventing damage to the Duet board if you were to accidentally connect it to 12v.

I believe the diode could be left out if you're quite certain that the sensor doesn't have an internal pull-up resistor and you're careful to connect it correctly. If in doubt, use the diode like they said.